# JQuery text function isn't showing the text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using JQuery on laravel 8 and I am trying to show "This field is required." when the date field becomes empty. However, when I remove the default value (todays date) nothing shows. If I put the date in the future, "The date can't be in the future." shows no bother. I can't find out why.
It is entering the "if (value === "")"

jquery

```
$(document).on("change", "#date", function(){
var value = $("#date").val();
if (value === ""){

  //this line doesn't show anything
  $("#dateError").text("This field is required.").css('color', '#ff0000').attr('class', 'col-6');
} else{
  $("#dateError").text("");
}
let today = new Date();
let inputDate = new Date(value);
if (inputDate > today){

// this will show
   $("#dateError").text("The date can't be in the future.").css('color', '#ff0000').attr('class', 'col-6');
} else{
   $("#dateError").text("");
}
})
```

html

```
<div class="row m-3">
  <label for="date" class="col-lg-2 me-2">Date<i>*</i></label>
  <input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="{{ old('date', now()->toDateString()) }}" class="col-lg-9"/>
</div>
<div class="row m-3">
  <span id="dateError"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is you are running the second `if()` regardless of what happens in the first and the second will overwrite text set in the first.

One fix would be to `return` when value is empty and after the error text has been set

```
if (value === ""){
  
  $("#dateError").text("This field is required.").css('color', '#ff0000').attr('class', 'col-6');

   // don't go any further 
   return;
} else ...
```

Comment: thanks, this sorted out my problem

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because of ===. Value is a date object, and you are comparing it to a string. And for the today variable, you created an instance only.

Comment: You can confirm that it is not a date object and is a string by running the code yourself rather than guessing